# C++ duplicate virtual function override when derived class overrides member variable

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

I have a base class and many derived classes, defined in the following way:

```
class BaseClass {

public: 
    virtual ClassType getClassType() {return classType;}

private:
    ClassType classType = BaseType;
}
```

```
class DerivedClass: public BaseClass {
public:
    ClassType getClassType() override {return classType;}

private:
    ClassType classType = DerivedType;
}
```

There are many similar derived classes of the same base class that share a similar structure.

I have a generator that keeps generating `BaseClass` objects, and each time I will call `x.getClassType()` to know its class type, then use `dynamic_cast` to cast it to the corresponding derived class.

The problem is, I have to write the same `getClassType()` function over and over again in each of the derived classes.

Is there anyway to just write the function only once, and each class will return their corresponding value of `classType` when called from a `BaseClass*`?

Comment: What is `ClassType` defined as in this code?

Comment: Note that *I will call `x.getClass()` to know its class type, then use `dynamic_cast` to cast it to corresponding derived class.* is considered to be an antipattern. Consider broadening the interface of the base class with `virtual` functions so that you don't need to know the type. If this doesn't make sense given wildly different interfaces for the various derived classes, look more closely at whether or not the [is-a relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) of inheritance is a good fit.

Comment: There is typeid operator in language but its usage for figuring into what you can dynamic_cast some base class pointer is considered smelly.

Comment: Unfortunately no, C++ does not work this way.

Comment: You currently have a 2 `ClassType classType` members in `DerivedClass`. Why don't you set it in a constructor (to `BaseType` in the base class, and to `DerivedType` in the derived class with a protected constructor)? That way `getClassType` doesn't have to be virtual

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I will call `x.getClassType()` to know its class type, then use `dynamic_cast` to cast it to the corresponding derived class.

If you know what an object's type is, you can use `static_cast` instead of `dynamic_cast`.  On the other hand, if you use `dynamic_cast`, you can get rid of `getClassType()` altogether, as you can just query the object whether it matches a given type.

> Is there anyway to just write the function only once, and each class will return their corresponding value of `classType` when called from a `BaseClass*`?

You only need one `classType` member, in the `BaseClass`, you don't need to repeat that member for each class.  As such, you can remove `virtual` from `getClassType()`, and then give `BaseClass` a constructor parameter to assign the `classType` member. That way, `DerivedClass` can then pass its type to the `BaseClass` constructor, eg:

```
class BaseClass {
public: 
    BaseClass(ClassType classType = BaseType) : classType(classType) {}

    ClassType getClassType() { return classType; }

private:
    ClassType classType;
};

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass {
public:
    DerivedClass() : BaseClass(DerivedType) {}
};
```

The downside to this approach is if you want to derive another class from `DerivedClass` later on, you will have to give `DerivedClass` a similar constructor to passed along the new class's type, eg:

```
class BaseClass {
public: 
    BaseClass(ClassType classType = BaseType) : classType(classType) {}

    ClassType getClassType() { return classType; }

private:
    ClassType classType;
};

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass {
public:
    BaseClass(ClassType classType = DerivedType) : classType(classType) {}
};

class AnotherClass : public DerivedClass {
public:
    AnotherClass() : DerivedClass(AnotherType) {}
};
```

Otherwise, you can leave `virtual` on `getClassType()`, and get rid of the `classType` member altogether. Simply have `BaseClass` and `DerivedClass` (and any subsequent classes) override `getClassType()` to directly return their respective type, eg:

```
class BaseClass {
public: 
    virtual ClassType getClassType() { return BaseType; }
};

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass {
public:
    ClassType getClassType() override { return DerivedType; }
};

class AnotherClass : public DerivedClass {
public:
    ClassType getClassType() override { return AnotherType; }
};
```